# Running nunit-tests from the command line

Tags: testing, mono, nunit, monodevelop, nunit-console

I get the following output when trying to run **nunit-console Testsuite.sln**

```
NUnit version 2.4.8
Copyright (C) 2002-2007 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 11.4.0.0
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.1433 ( 2.10.11 (mono-2-10/2baeee2 Wed Jan 16 16:40:16 EST 2013) )

Missing method .ctor in assembly /Users/administrator/Desktop/projectname/testsuite/bin/Debug/Testsuite.dll, type NUnit.Framework.TestFixtureAttribute
Can't find custom attr constructor image: /Users/administrator/Desktop/projectname/testsuite/bin/Debug/Testsuite.dll mtoken: 0x0a000004
Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework, Version=2.6.0.12051, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies.
```

Any suggestions? Running the test from the testrunner in mono develop works without problems.

Comment: Might be way off but it's not a version conflict is it? Version running is 2.4.8, and it's looking for nunit.framework 2.6.0?

Comment: Didn't know that the nunit console version has to match the nunit version - will look for that, thanks so far.

Comment: Okay, tried running it through NUnit 2.6.0.12051 -> Output stays the same: http://pastebin.com/Ccm7acm9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not finding your nunit.framework.dll file, I think you have a borked installation. How did you install mono? How did you install NUnit?

Although I would recommend to fix your mono/nunit installation first, a possible workaround would be:

1. Find where is nunit.framework.dll, by doing for example: find /usr | grep nunit
2. Run nunit this way:

`MONO_PATH=/path/where/nunit/dlls/are nunit-console4 Testsuite.dll`

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! I have not found any nunit.framework.dll at all - mono was installed by Xamarin (formerly Mono Touch). Maybe this is the reason why the mono installation was not properly.

Comment: oh, I thought you were in Linux; then open a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ and they will fix it right away so you don't need the hack anymore